# Unresolved reference: SavedStateVMFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I am following the "Guide to app architecture" (Jetpack) and it cannot resolve references as below.

[image: Unresolved reference: SavedStateVMFactory]

I already added the libraries:

build.gradle (Module: app):

```
def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

build.gradle (Project: ProjectName)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()    
    }
}
```

What is missing to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's two issues:

1) ViewModel-SavedState is a separate artifact that needs to be included:

```
def viewmodel_savedstate_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

2) As per the [1.0.0-alpha02 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate-1.0.0-alpha02):

> `SavedStateVMFactory` is renamed to `SavedStateViewModelFactory`.

So make sure you're using `SavedStateViewModelFactory` in any place where you would otherwise have used `SavedStateVMFactory`.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, it solved the SavedStateVMFactory but keyword "viewModels" is still unresolved. I need another artifact?

Comment: `by viewModels` is a Kotlin property delegate on Fragment, so it would be part of `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx`. It was added in [Fragments `1.1.0-alpha03`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-alpha03), so using the latest (`1.1.0-rc01` as of right now) would be your best bet.